# Updating documents fields using lucene

Tags: java, lucene

i'm trying to update an indexed documents in lucene by searching for the document, and then extracting the indexed document fields, and then deleting the document and creating a new one.
is there anther effective way for such an update?

Answer (score 3):

There isn't. The best you can get is `IndexWriter.updateDocument(Term term, Iterable<? extends IndexableField> document)` but even this deletes and adds the same document again.